# Suppress warning by unicode-math regarding mathtools

Tags: warnings, unicode-math, mathtools

When using the packages `unicode-math` and `mathtools`, I always get warnings

```
Package unicode-math Warning: Using \overbracket and \underbracket from
(unicode-math)                `mathtools' package.
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                 Use \Uoverbracket and \Uunderbracket for
(unicode-math)                original `unicode-math' definition.


Package unicode-math Warning: I'm going to overwrite the following commands
(unicode-math)                from the `mathtools' package: 
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                     \dblcolon, \coloneqq, \Coloneqq, \eqqcolon.
(unicode-math)                
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                 Note that since I won't overwrite the other
(unicode-math)                colon-like commands, using them will lead to
(unicode-math)                inconsistencies.
```

(and sometimes a few more of the same kind). In the documentation for `unicode-math`, Sec. 6.1, I find

> This package can produce a number of informational messages to try and inform
> the user when something might be going wrong due to package conflicts or some-
> thing else. As an experimental feature, these can be turn off on an individual ba-
> sis with the package option warnings-off which takes a comma-separated list
> of warnings to suppress.

However the only warning that is mentioned by name is `mathtools-colon`:

> This warning could be suppressed by loading the package as follows:
>
> `\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon}]{unicode-math}`

How can I suppress all warnings of `unicode-math` regarding `mathtools`?

Comment: Looking at the `unicode-math` code there is only a further warning `mathtool-overbracket`, so `\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}` should work. But it's indeed a bit disappointing that no easier way is available.

Comment: @campa Please write that as an answer because it is the correct solution!

Comment: @Adam Uh, I had completely forgotten about this. I was actually hoping that some `unicode-math` expert would slip in and answer properly, but all right, I'll write one, be it only to take the question from the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: @campa Your comment solved my problem and as it helped me, I merely suggested that because I thought you would have forgotten it and it would be a shame such a helpful tip to go unnoticed. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 15):

As far as I can see the `unicode-math` documentation does not state explicitly which warnings are predefined. Searching the code for the string `mathtools` one finds the lines

```
\msg_new:nnn { unicode-math } { mathtools-overbracket } {
  Using~ \token_to_str:N \overbracket\ and~
         \token_to_str:N \underbracket\ from~
 `mathtools'~ package.\\
  \\
  Use~ \token_to_str:N \Uoverbracket\ and~
       \token_to_str:N \Uunderbracket\ for~
       original~ `unicode-math'~ definition.
}
\msg_new:nnn { unicode-math } { mathtools-colon } {
  I'm~ going~ to~ overwrite~ the~ following~ commands~ from~
  the~ `mathtools'~ package: \\ \\
  \ \ \ \ \token_to_str:N \dblcolon,~
  \token_to_str:N \coloneqq,~
  \token_to_str:N \Coloneqq,~
  \token_to_str:N \eqqcolon. \\ \\
  Note~ that~ since~ I~ won't~ overwrite~ the~ other~ colon-like~
  commands,~ using~ them~ will~ lead~ to~ inconsistencies.
}
```

so the `mathtools`-related warnings are `mathtools-overbracket` and `mathtools-colon`. To deactivate them load the package as

```
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
```