# Warning when unicode-math and mathtools are loaded

Tags: unicode-math, warnings, mathtools

This is a follow-up question to "[Switching from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659620/switching-from-pdflatex-to-lualatex)".

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

When compiliing using `lualatex`, I get the warning

```
Package unicode-math Warning: Using \overbracket and \underbracket from
(unicode-math)                `mathtools' package.
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                 Use \Uoverbracket and \Uunderbracket for
(unicode-math)                original `unicode-math' definition.


Package unicode-math Warning: I'm going to overwrite the following commands
(unicode-math)                from the `mathtools' package: 
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                     \dblcolon, \coloneqq, \Coloneqq, \eqqcolon.
(unicode-math)                
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                 Note that since I won't overwrite the other
(unicode-math)                colon-like commands, using them will lead to
(unicode-math)                inconsistencies.
```

Can this be resolved and if so, then how do I do it?

Comment: what resolution would you want? unicode-math has resolved it, and just let you know

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would like to be able to use `\dblcolon`, `\coloneqq`, `\Coloneqq`, and `\eqqcolon` as they are meant in the `mathtools` package.

Comment: mathtools actually changed these definitions earlier this year so not sure it makes any difference but `\usepackage{mathtools}\let\mtdblcolon\dblcolon
\usepackage{unicode-math}` will save the mathtools version

Comment: Thank you very much! If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570548/82917 (shameless self-publicity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) actually changed these definitions earlier this year so not sure it makes any difference but

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\let\mtdblcolon\dblcolon
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

will save the [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) version.