# unicode-math and mathtools symbol naming clash doesn't seem to be an issue?

Tags: unicode-math, mathtools

I got an error from Overleaf/LuaLaTeX saying that i have the following errors:

> Package unicode-math Warning: Using \overbracket and \underbracket from `mathtools' package. Use \Uoverbracket and \Uunderbracket for original` unicode-math' definition.

> Package unicode-math Warning: I'm going to overwrite the following commands from the `mathtools' package: \dblcolon, \coloneqq, \Coloneqq, \eqqcolon. Note that since I won't overwrite the other colon-like commands, using them will lead to inconsistencies.

The comment that talks about inconsistencies with other colon like commands concerned me, so i investigated how these are affected.

...and... it *doesn't have my symbols affected?* when i tried to run each symbol available according to the `mathtools` package with all of them, while changing the 4 symbols the warning talks about, it didn't seem to change the way they looked, and it honestly surprised me.

is this warning redundant now? i want to be able to use the `mathtools` package names for the symbols, but it seems like it doesnt matter if i choose the `unicode-math` or `mathtools` versions of the 4 commands. Here is the code showing this.

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

Last 4 using \texttt{unicode-math} names

\begin{equation}
\approxcolon \colondash \Approxcolon \Colondash \simcolon \dashcolon \Simcolon \Dashcolon \colonapprox \Colonapprox \colonsim \Colonsim \Eqcolon \dblcolon \coloneqq \Coloneqq \eqqcolon
\end{equation}

Last 4 using \texttt{mathtools}

\begin{equation}
\approxcolon \colondash \Approxcolon \Colondash \simcolon \dashcolon \Simcolon \Dashcolon \colonapprox \Colonapprox \colonsim \Colonsim \Eqcolon \dblcolon \coloneq \Coloneq \eqcolon
\end{equation}

...they're the same?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570548/suppress-warning-by-unicode-math-regarding-mathtools

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that a code example should always be a _minimal working exmaple_ (MWE), where both _minimal_ and _working_ are important. I edited yours to be more minimal.

Answer (score 4):

First off, these are warnings, not errors. They tell you that there is something you may want to be aware off, but it's not a problem for typesetting on a technical level.

Now, the warning says: "I'm going to **overwrite** the following commands from the `mathtools' package [...]" Thus, in your example, you are not actually using the original `mathtools` symbols; they have been overwritten with the `unicode-math` versions. The fact that both symbol names result in the same symbol is thus expected.

The warning tells you that there may be inconsistencies between those symbols and the ones that are not overwritten, which is indeed the case. For example, look at `\coloneq` and `\colonsim`:

[image: inconsistent colons]

Comment: Thank you brother for the answer, but you need to add a bit of clarification. When you say in my example where I'm differentiating the last 4 versions of the 4 commands in the warning, these are all `unicode-math` names? And how can there be inconsistencies if i am seeing both lines have all the symbols the same way?

Comment: i simply want to use the `mathtools` versions of symbols and have inconsistencies be avoided

Comment: @FerriusUndermine The inconsistencies are not between your two lines of symbols, they are within each line. Again, look at the screenshot in my answer. As you can see, the colons in the two symbols are very different; the `unicode-math` symbols (under any name) have a narrower spacing.

Comment: @FerriusUndermine I do not believe that an interface to prevent overwriting these names is provided. You can undo the effect manually, of course. Please ask a separate question for help with this.

Comment: "The inconsistencies are not between your two lines of symbols, they are within each line." Alright, yes. i do see the difference in the picture. I would like to use the narrower spaced version of `\colonsim`, but how does one get the less spaced versions of the commands? https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools?lang=en the package documentation pdf on page 31 lists commands, and these are all spaced less.

Comment: @FerriusUndermine Well, how your symbols look is a question of your font. For example, using the standard font you will get consistent symbols. It looks like `XITS Math` does not provide the same. If you want to use all of the symbols, I recommend switching fonts.

Comment: thank you brother for answering, in the mathtools pdf `\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}` as the math font is what seems to be the default font, but i actually seem to have weirdly changed by mind, and like `STIX Two Math` more as my font. **i just want to make sure**, if i use `dblcolon`, `coloneq`, `Coloneq` and `eqcolon`, **OR** `dblcolon`, `coloneqq`, `Coloneqq` and `eqqcolon`, and don't mind any font difference, i shouldn't have to worry about the inconsistencies or any naming issues? thank you for putting up with my questions, I'm grateful for all the answers you've given.

Comment: i hope i haven't annoyed you with this question. also the post now uses`STIX Two Math`.

Comment: and if `unicode-math` symbols is the easier/safer way to do stuff ill just use their commands, but since you say that the 8 commands are `unicode-math` i guess this proposition is not needed

Comment: @FerriusUndermine Nothing is safer/unsafe. Just find a font you like, pick one set of names (personally, I prefer the `eq` names to the `eqq` ones) and stick with that.